# regular expression to modify a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I  have a string that I need to modify. The part that I need to modify is the end of the string. It is something like "to 23 May 2017". I just need to change the date that it is stored.

So I tried something like this:

```
var texto = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(test, "to "+@"^\d{1,2}\/\?[A-z]?\/\d{4}","to { refundEnd: dd MMM yyyy}");
```

However, there is a problem with the regular expression because I am not matching the date. 
I am using the 'to' because there is another date in the string but this one does not need to be modified.

Any ideas?

Comment: Date at the end of the string, or the date after `to`? Try just `Regex.Replace(test, @"\b(to\s*)\d{1,2}\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*\d{4}\b", "$1{ refundEnd: dd MMM yyyy}")`

Comment: How are you deciding what the new date will be? Is it based on the original date, or is the original date not important? If you don't need it, then it would be much simpler to just remove everything after "to" and then append whatever date you want

Comment: Does this help: (.)* to (?<Date>\d{2} [a-z,A-Z]+ \d{4})$

Comment: What is the source string and what is the desired result?

Comment: Your regex starts with `"to ^"`, but `^` is the start-of-line anchor.

Comment: You might get a better use of `$` as the end-of-line marker. \

Comment: the new date is set up by user.

Comment: the source string looks like this "Direct Debit Refund: Direct Debit refund for Meals (02 Feb 2017 to 11 May 2017).", I 'm only interested in modifying the second date, thanks

Comment: Then try my solution in the top comment. And it still sounds a bit unclear. Please add these details to the question. Am I right `{ refundEnd: dd MMM yyyy}` is a hardcoded replacement string?

Comment: it was coming from a website, however, it is a string and I can't change that, because it is a big project and it will impact some other parts of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is only really useful in this instance if you actually want to do something with the date before you replace it (for example, the new date will be based on the current date). However, this doesn't seem to be the case based on your question.

If your date format is always going to be the same length, then you could always just trim off `x` characters from the end. But your current attempt suggests that the day part of the date will be unknown length (either one or two digits). Based on that I would suggest the best approach would be to use the position of `"to"` to identify what should be removed.

You could do this 2 different ways, take your pick:

---

**The SPLIT method**

Split the string on `"to"` and then rebuild the new string:

```
string[] values = test.Split("to");
string result = string.Format("{0} to {1}", values[0].Trim(), newDateString);
```

---

**The SUBSTRING method**

Create a substring based on the last index of `"to"` (we use last index in case there are any other matches earlier on in the string) which will provide you everything before `"to"`. Then you can append the rest on to the end:

```
string result = string.Format("{0} to {1}", test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf("to")).Trim(), newDateString);
```

Comment: using `LastIndexOf` is probably a better solution then `IndexOf`, in this case.

Comment: Well, there are bottlenecks with this approach: 1) `to` is searched for inside all words, not as a whole word, 2) with `LastIndexOf`, the second solution is close but if you see [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886040/regular-expression-to-modify-a-string#comment80720389_46886040), the date is not at the very end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: hmmm... perhaps the OP should put that vital piece of information in the question

Answer (score -1):

In the end, what it worked for me was this:

```
var texto = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
        .Replace(test, @"to\s+(\d{1,2})\s+([A-z]+)\s+(\d{4})", "to " 
         + refundEnd.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));
```

It is a combination of two issues:

1.- getting the proper regular expression.
2.- formatting the new date.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: `[A-z]` makes little sense.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go.

```
var texto = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(test, @"to\s+(\d{1,2})\s+([A-z]+)\s+(\d{4})","to { refundEnd: $1 $2 $3}");
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but 1) `[A-z]` matches more than just letters, 2) the expected result does not seem to be a reformatted  date but a hardcoded template substring. And besides, code only answers do not really add value. Especially, when it comes to regex where a single whitespace matters.

Comment: True. Original issues with op's regex were excess backslashes, lack of whitespace -operators and incorrect usage of quantifiers, so I'll leave mine as it is just as reference.

Comment: Answer does not explain the problem and it does not highlight what your changes are and how they solve the issue. Also the other problems mentioned by Wiktor

Comment: also, it does not accept now what it is stored in refundEnd variable, even if it is used like that somewhere else and it works there

Answer (score -3):

You can just remove the last 11 characters and concatenate the new date you want to suffix it with.

```
 //Your New Date string
 String yourDate = "dd MMM YYYY";
 var texto = test.Remove(test.Length - 11, 11)+yourDate;
```

Comment: `\d{1,2}` means that the date is not a fixed length substring.